# MVC4 Ajax.BeginForm routeValues converted to Type Name in HTML

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ajax.beginform

I'm using Ajax.BeginForm in a MVC 4 Razor View.

```
@model EditViewDefinition
@{
    RouteValueDictionary postParams = new RouteValueDictionary();
    postParams.Add("entityUid", Model.EntityUid);
    postParams.Add("entityId", ViewBag.entityId);
    postParams.Add("viewUid", Model.UID);
    string viewContainerId = "viewcontent_" + Model.UID.ToString().ToLower() + "_" + ViewBag.entityId.ToString();
}
```

then

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", postParams, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post", OnSuccess = "submitSuccess('" + viewContainerId + "')" }))
{
...
}
```

Now when I check the resulting HTML in the browser, I get:

```
<form id="form0" 
    action="/View/Edit?Count=3&amp;Keys=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%2BKeyCollection%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.Object%5D&amp;Values=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%2BValueCollection%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.Object%5D"
    method="post" 
    data-ajax-success="submitSuccess('viewcontent_fb1a8d4c-fd30-4da4-b11c-bff99f3bb74f_1')" 
    data-ajax-method="Post" 
    data-ajax="true"> 

    ... 
</form>
```

Why am I getting **System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%2BKeyCollection%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.Object** in the action attribute instead of **action="/View/Edit?entityUid=uid&entityId=1&viewUid=uid**?

Comment: Have you tried just `var postParams = new { entityUid = Model.EntityUid, entityId = ViewBag.entityId, viewUid = Model.UID };`

Comment: Thanks a lot Stephen, that worked perfectly. WOW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Stephen Muecke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3559349/stephen-muecke)'s comment. I used `var postParams = new { entityUid = Model.EntityUid, entityId = ViewBag.entityId, viewUid = Model.UID };` which worked.

Many Thanks Stephen.